# How can I duplicate a pandas dataframe, to make it 2 variables?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

How can I convert one pandas dataframe into 2, so I can operate on both independently on the 2 newly created frames? Looks like when I assign it to a new variable by using "=", it is doing some kind of "assing by reference", not actually duplicating the dataframe.

Here is what I do. I start by loading a CSV file into df_data

```
df_data = pd.read_csv(input_filename, usecols=colList, skiprows=2)
```

Works like a charm. But this set contains mixed rows (training and testing data for a ML project), so I want to split the sets. In a nutshell: Duplicate the dataset, then in the newly created `df_train_data` delete all rows with flag "test", and vice versa:

```
df_train_data = df_data
df_train_data.drop(df_train_data[df_train_data['Usage']=='test'].index, inplace=True)
del df_train_data['Usage']
df_test_data = df_data
df_test_data.drop(df_test_data[df_test_data['Usage']=='train'].index, inplace=True)
del df_test_data['Usage']
```

Now this produces an error. After I delete the "Usage" colum (row 3 above) in `df_train_data`, it also disapears from `df_data`, and hence produces an error in row 6, given it does not exist in `df_test_data`.

I also see the rows I thought I would delete only in `df_train_data` have disappeared entirely...

Why? How can I hard-copy `df_data` into 2 dataframes, and then work on both independently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the [copy](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.copy.html) function:

```
df_train_data = df_data.copy()
```

Comment: My goodness... I cannot believe how basic my question was. Then again: What is this good for? I mean ... a = b also works, right? Why would this need to be re-written as a = b.copy?

Comment: @KingOtto `a = b` creates a second reference to the _same_ object. If you make change to object b, they'll be seen in object a but both variables point to the same object in memory. By using copy, you will have 2 independent objects.

Answer (score 0):

This would be more readable:

```
df_train_data = df_data[df_test_data['Usage']=='train'].drop('Usage', axis=1)
df_test_data = df_data[df_test_data['Usage']=='test'].drop('Usage', axis=1)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Really so much easier. Minor typo, though, it should be `df_train_data = df_data[df_data['Usage']=='train'].drop('Usage', axis=1)`, right?